# Finding derivative of $x^3-17x$ using limit definition

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Could someone help me with the algebra that comes with finding the derivative of $x^3-17x$ using the limit definition of:

[image: 1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We msut compute this limit,

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{(x+h)^3-17x-17h-x^3+17x}{h}=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{3x^2 h+3xh^2+h^3-17h}{h}=\lim_{h \to 0} (3x^2+3xh+h^2-17)=3x^2-17 $$

Therefore $\frac{d}{dx} (x^3-17x)=3x^2-17$.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I prefer $d(x^3-17x)/dx = 3x^2 - 17$. :-)

Comment: @ÉricGuirbal, Go through the OP. He wanted to achieve the differential using first principle of derivative..

Comment: @SubhadeepDey: He made a little mistake.

Comment: @ÉricGuirbal Where?

Comment: @ÉricGuirbal, Where?

Comment: @Aleksandar: You first wrote $3x^2 + 17$ instead of $3x^2-17$.

Comment: @ÉricGuirbal,No, It's $-(x^3-17x)=-x^3+17x.$ Did you made out?